# Cannot Get Route using express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I can get my about page to route incorrectly . I can't get my Palindrome and feedback to route at all. I have gone over it and seem to be missing something , or has something that's causing the issue.

my error

express:router dispatching GET /feedback +2s

express:router query  : /feedback +0ms

express:router expressInit  : /feedback +0ms

express:router logger  : /feedback +0ms

express:router serveStatic  : /feedback +0ms

send stat "C:\Users\johns\Documents\SCC-GIT\FinalProjectCis258\final-

project\public\feedback" +2s

finalhandler default 404 +0ms

morgan log request +2s

GET /feedback 404 147 - 2.074 ms

app.js file looks like this

```
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const chalk = require("chalk");
const debug = require("debug")("app");
const morgan = require("morgan");
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const finalRouter = require("./src/routes/finalRoutes")();

const port = process.env.PORT ?? "4000";

app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"/public/")));


//   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//   app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.set("views",path.join(__dirname,"src","views"));
 app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(
   "/css",
   express.static(
     path.join(__dirname, "node_modules", "bootstrap", "dist", "css")
   )
 );
 app.use(
   "/js",
   express.static(
     path.join(__dirname, "node_modules", "bootstrap", "dist", "js")
   )
 );
```

My controller file looks like this

```
function finalController() {
    function getAbout(req,res) {
        res.render("about");
    }
      function getFeedback(req,res) {
        res.render("feedback");
    }

    function getPalindrome(req,res) {
        res.render("palindrome");
    }
    
    return {
        getAbout,
        getFeedback,
        getPalindrome
    }
}

module.exports = finalController;
```

and my routes look like this

````
const router = express.Router();

const controller = require("../controllers/finalController");

// const routes = (req,res) => {
//     res.render("about");
// };

function routes () {
    const{getAbout,getFeedback,getPalindrome} = controller();

    router.route("/about").get(getAbout);

    router.route("/palindrome").get(getPalindrome);

    router.route("/feedback").get(getFeedback);

    return router;
}
module.exports = routes;```
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be an issue with your route definitions. Specifically, you have two routes defined for the root ("/") path in your router. You should use different paths for each route. Also, you need to make sure that you are using the correct method for the routes.

Here's a modified version of your routes:

```js
const router = express.Router();

const controller = require("../controllers/finalController");

function routes() {
    const { getAbout, getFeedback, getPalindrome } = controller();

    // Define separate routes for each path
    router.route("/about").get(getAbout);

    router.route("/palindrome").get(getPalindrome);

    router.route("/feedback").get(getFeedback);

    return router;
}

module.exports = routes;
```

In this modified version, I changed the root ("/") route to "/about" and added a new route for "/palindrome". Make sure to update your navigation links or API calls accordingly in your client code.

Now, when you visit "/about" or "/palindrome", it should render the corresponding views. If the issue persists, check your view files, and ensure they are in the correct directory and have the correct file extensions.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to change them back before posting. I am only able to get the About page to work with the right root.  my  links in the index are  <nav class="nav justify-content-end ">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/palindrome"> Palindrome</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/feedback"> Feedback</a>
      </nav>